# Antminer 22nm or 14nm?

Tags: antminer

I currently have two offers for buying antminer s9. One with a 22nm chip and the other with 14nm. Can somebody give be the pros and cons for both, because i understand that the power consumption would be bigger with the 22nm, but will that mean that i will be mining less than the 14th/s -+ 5% ? or will the electricity be only different. Hoping to have a good response and answer from you, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

14nm will hash more with the same power consumption of a 22nm assuming your basing it on power only. But if both were 1/ths the 14nm would save more electricity. Obviously the 14nm would cost more as its newer tech. You'd have to weigh your electric cost vs hashing power.

Comment: I think the question is whether they have the same maximum hash rate, regardless of power consumed.

Comment: both actually. All other comparisons are the same, i think that probably the 22nm use more electricity /but to what extend is the question? And probably the risk of getting hotter and thus frieing some part and wrecking the miner is bigger, but it all depends on the care i take of it. Still both say are 14th/s, i think that the one with 22nm will probably go 11,5+ and consume around 1500kw but is this the case or im in the wrong direction. My main reason to know is that i can get one for 2300 usd and the other at 700 like i said all aspects are the same except the use of the chip.